# Is there a way to edit field name, type & length after importing from Excel?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, import, excel, editing

Is there a way to edit the name, type and length given to each column on the attribute table once the information has been imported from Excel?

Comment: You might look at the table manager plugin to rename a field.  I don't know of an easy way to change field types; I would probably create a field with the proper type and length, and then copy data into it.

Comment: I believe @johns comment should be seen as the answer for this question. Other than changing the name of the field (column) by either the _Table manager_ plugin or adding an Alias (_Layer properties_ > _Fields_), I don't think you can change its type or length once it has been created. As already suggested, copying the data using the Field Calculator is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thank you the Table Manager Plug In is doing just what I needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: @johns, could you move your comment as the answer (maybe adding bits from Joseph's comment as well) this question please?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the table manager plugin to rename a field. I don't know of an easy way to change field types; I would probably create a field with the proper type and length, and then copy data into it.  As Joseph suggested you can add an alias for use in that project.